# Css Image Path Error (ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: html, css

With CSS when I try to add a background image with a relative path, the browser does not find it :

```
background-image: url("img/cover.jpg");
```

> ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

But if I use an absolute path, the image appears :

```
background-image: url("file:///E:/website/img/cover.jpg");
```

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place img folder and .css file on same directory (for Example if img directory is located on "website" then style.css file must be located on same directory "website")

OR

If css file is located on some other like in "website/css" directory then use "`../`' before img.

for example

```
background-image: url("../img/cover.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the .css files in another folder.
Suppose if you have the folder structure like this -

website
|-css
| |-style.css
|-js
|-img
| |-cover.jpg

then you have to give path from where your .css file is placed.

So, instead of `background-image: url("img/cover.jpg");`,
try `background-image: url("../img/cover.jpg");`
or give path from the root, like `background-image: url("/img/cover.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Check even this works well!

If you can use style.css from "css (folder name)" folder then you have to use relative path

1. For eg. background-image: url("../img/cover.jpg");  And if you can
   use style.css or internal css(style in html file) same level as
   'img' folder then you have to use 'folder-name/img.jpg'
2. For eg. background-image: url("img/cover.jpg");